# A taxonomy of web frameworks?

Tags: frameworks

There seem to be several different categories of web frameworks, e.g. MVC, component based, event-driven, action-based, etc.

I can't find a comprehensive list of categories and definitions anywhere.  (I dare not ask for examples as well.)  Is there a general taxonomy of web application frameworks somewhere, or is this too fuzzy a question to allow for definitive answers?

Comment: See also: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1190953

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there is an article which can be helpful:

http://blog.websitesframeworks.com/2013/02/web-frameworks-types-122/

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Matt Raible does a pretty good job on [comparing and describing java web frameworks](http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/my_comparing_jvm_web_frameworks):